# Using GET method to get href attribute of an object

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

What i'm trying to do is what i thought would be quite easy, but it doesnt seem to be working. I want to get the href of an object and all the function is returning is `undefined`.

[This is the page](http://m.roblox.com/items/24826737/privatesales/) that i'm requesting and what i'm trying to retrieve is the href held in the element of the first seller (who's `ClassName` is `ui-link-inherit`)

```
var buy = $.get(
    "http://m.roblox.com/items/24826737/privatesales/",
    function (data){
        alert($(data).find(".ui-link-inherit:eq(0)").attr('href'));
    }
);
```

I thought it was a permissions issue at first but it still wont work even if you run that on the page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I tried a couple of the solutions suggested in that question and nothing really seemed to work. This isnt really complex so i'm not sure what's wrong with it.

Comment: Don't use the solutions, read the answers, carefully. When you do `var buy =` buy is not equal to the result of the AJAX response - since the AJAX result is not even ready yet, since it's asynchronous.

Comment: Well then this should work too, but it doesnt: function getHREF(){
 $.get(
  "http://m.roblox.com/items/24826737/privatesales/",
  function (data){
   alert($(data).find(".ui-link-inherit:eq(0)").attr('href'));
  }
 );
}

getHREF();

Comment: I don't see a `.ui-link-inherit` element on the page. Do I need to be logged in? That could be the problem.

Comment: @Thomas, I logged out and tried it and `ui-link-inherit` is still there.

Comment: I don't know why but I don't see it. What browser are you using? Do you have any cookies or other local data (localStorage, sessionStorage etc.)

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but @Fuzzyma below (I think) is on to something. If the elements are loaded via javascript after the page has loaded then they wont be able to be fetched through GET

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to just alert the data you get?
If there is no `.ui-link-inherit` ofc it wont work and since `.ui-link-inherit` seems to be a class of jqueryUI which adds the classes after the page is loaded via javascript, you wont get this class via `GET`

//EDIT: I dont get all this "you cant access the data cause ajax is asynchronus". He is using the get-fukction completely right. He can access `data` since `data` IS the returned stuff from the server. Did I miss something that you all get this that way?

Comment: If you go to the page, this will work: `alert($(document).find(".ui-link-inherit:eq(0)").attr('href'));`

Comment: Are you using the console to execute this Javascipt? If so ofc the class is there cause it was added after DOM-load. How you execute the javascript on that site?

Comment: I think you're right about the javascript loading. I wont be able to load the elements if theyre loaded via JS

Comment: You are loading this side via ajax. That means you get the orginal html without any changes. To get the element you want you have to search for another path to the element.

Comment: I really dont know how to do that, but thanks anyways

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a value from that function, it is executed asynchronously.  Instead just wait for the AJAX to finish and then do something with the result

```
// don't do this 
// var buy = $.get(... etc...);
// the variable buy will never have any value

// do this instead
function getHREF(){ 
    $.get(
          "http://m.roblox.com/items/24826737/privatesales/",
          function (data){
              var buy = $(data).find(".ui-link-inherit:eq(0)").attr('href');
              doSomething(buy);
          }
    );
)};

function doSomething(buy) {
    // in here do whatever you want with the ajax data 
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    getHREF();
});
```

Comment: Inside of the `doSomething` function, i put `alert(buy);` which still didn't work.

Answer (score -1):

The site does not allow Cross-site HTTP requests. Read here: [HTTP access control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

Comment: Just because your code as it is does not work on the site, does not mean that you will be able to get it to work on yours.

Comment: I'm not worried about it working on my site. That wasn't my original question.

Comment: OK, sorry. If you wish to make an ajax call in a browser to this particular site, it will have to be run on the same domain. If you are not able to publish your site onto this domain, then it will not work.